# Django Celery Recursive Error With tasks.py, Not With views.py

Tags: django, recursion, celery

I've created a recursive function to get all children of a certain object.

```
    def get_all_children(self):
    children = [self]
    try:
        child_list = self.children.all()
    except AttributeError:
        return children
    for child in child_list:
        children.extend(child.get_all_children())
    return children
```

It works fine when I call this function in my views.py file. But it gives me a
**RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison**
when I call the same function in my celery tasks.py file

Comment: This has nothing to do with celery/views. You likely made a loop somewhere, so where a node has a child, and that child has the original node as child.

Comment: Exactly mate. I Accidentally made a loop. Thanks a lot